# Truncate Value in Sharepoint Workflow in SPD2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a workflow in SharePoint 2010 that takes 2 separate columns from the same list and combines them. One is a column of products and the other is a simple number column that I've set to have **no** decimals. The combination is the form

```
combination=product-number
*ie* product1-1
```

When I run this workflow, however, the return is

```
product1-1.00000000000000
```

How do I truncate the ending zeroes? It is always 14 zeroes after the decimal.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of your number column?

Comment: @NomanFarooqi the number column is a _number_ type that is limited to 0 decimal places. It behaves like that in the original list. But when placed in the combination column (which is single line of text), the decimal places go to 14